# Diagonals in winning conditions in connect four program are not working correctly and I do not know why

Tags: matlab, matrix, connect-four

My winning conditions for rows and columns works completely fine. However, my diagonals do not. It will say you have won if you get your own number in 4 different rows and not in a direct diagonal as the game is meant to be played.

```
%check if won by columns
for column = 1:7
    counter = 0;
    for row = 1:6
        if(board(row,column) == players(1,2))
            counter = counter + 1;
            if(counter == 4)
                fprintf('You win! \n')
                break
            end
        else
            counter = 0;
        end
    end
end

%check if won by rows
for row = 1:6
    counter = 0;
    for column = 1:7
        if(board(row, column) == players(1,2))
            counter = counter + 1;
            if(counter == 4)
                fprintf('You win! \n')
                break
            end
        else 
            counter = 0;
        end
    end
end

%check if won by diagonal \ 1
for column = 1:4
    for row = 1:3
        counter = 0;
        if(board(row, column) == players(1))
            counter = (row+1), (column+1), (row+2), (column+2), (row+3), (column+3);
            if(counter == 4)
                fprintf('You win! \n')
                break
            end
        else 
            counter = 0;
        end
    end
end




%check if won by diagonal / 1
for column = 7:-1:4
    for row = 1:3
    counter = 0;
        if(board(row, column) == players(1))
            counter = (row+1), (column-1), (row+2), (column-2), (row+3), (column-3);
            if(counter == 4)
                fprintf('You win! \n')
                break
            end
        else 
            counter = 0;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: This code is not valid MATLAB syntax. Or better said: I don't think the syntax you have does what you think it does. What do you expect from `counter = (row+1), (column+1), (row+2), (column+2), (row+3), (column+3);` ? Because its the same as `counter = row+1`;

Comment: You should use the debugger to step through your code to see where it does something different from what you expect.